# how do I write a dafny function that checks if an array is sorted?

Tags: dafny

I want to write a dafny function, the same as the predicate below, so that I can call it from another function (in the code). However, I am not sure how I would go about doing this.

```
predicate sorted(s: seq<char>)
{
   forall i,j :: 0 <= i < j < |s| ==> s[i] <= s[j]
}
```

EDIT: So I tried the below, and got the error: stdin.dfy(8,8): Error: Assignment to non-ghost variable is not allowed in this context (because this is a ghost method or because the statement is guarded by a specification-only expression)

in reference to the line b := a

```
method sortString(a: string) returns (b: string) 

{
    if (sorted(a)){
      b := a;
    }
}

function sorted(s: seq<char>):bool
{
   if forall i,j :: 0 <= i < j < |s| ==> s[i] <= s[j] then true else false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to call `sorted` from a `method`, just mark it as a `predicate method`, like this

```
predicate method sorted(s: seq<char>)
{
   forall i,j :: 0 <= i < j < |s| ==> s[i] <= s[j]
}
```

Then you can call it from a `method` like this

```
method sortString(a: string) returns (b: string) 

{
    if (sorted(a)){
      b := a;
    }
}
```

Also, in general, a `predicate` is just a `function` that returns `bool`. There is no difference between the two.